# How do I create a CSV file using several lists as columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)

json_data_file <- file.choose()
json_data <- fromJSON(file=json_data_file)

buckets <- json_data$aggregations$my_date_histo$buckets
# filesystem_used_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) x$filesystem_used_pct$value)
# system_core_user_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) x$system_core_user_pct$value)
# system_core_system_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) x$system_core_system_pct$value)
# system_memory_actual_used_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) x$system_memory_actual_used_pct$value)
# system_memory_swap_used_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) x$system_memory_swap_used_pct$value)
# system_cpu_total_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) x$system_cpu_total_pct$value)
# system_cpu_system_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) x$system_cpu_system_pct$value)
# key <- lapply(buckets, function(x) x$key_as_string)

filesystem_used_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x$filesystem_used_pct$value), NA, x$filesystem_used_pct$value))
system_core_user_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x$system_core_user_pct$value), NA, x$system_core_user_pct$value))
system_core_system_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x$system_core_system_pct$value), NA, x$system_core_system_pct$value))
system_memory_actual_used_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x$system_memory_actual_used_pct$value), NA, x$system_memory_actual_used_pct$value))
system_memory_swap_used_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x$system_memory_swap_used_pct$value), NA, x$system_memory_swap_used_pct$value))
system_cpu_total_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x$system_cpu_total_pct$value), NA, x$system_cpu_total_pct$value))
system_cpu_system_pct_value <- lapply(buckets, function(x) ifelse(is.null(x$system_cpu_system_pct$value), NA, x$system_cpu_system_pct$value))

length(filesystem_used_pct_value)
length(system_core_user_pct_value)
length(system_core_system_pct_value)
length(system_memory_actual_used_pct_value)
length(system_memory_swap_used_pct_value)
length(system_cpu_total_pct_value)
length(system_cpu_system_pct_value)
length(key)

df <- data.frame(filesystem_used_pct_value,system_core_user_pct_value,system_core_system_pct_value,system_memory_actual_used_pct_value,system_memory_swap_used_pct_value,system_cpu_total_pct_value,system_cpu_system_pct_value)
write.csv(df, "elastic_aggs_metric.csv")
```

I've tried using c, converting to a matrix and the above but R complains of lengths being different or shoving everything to a single line. All the lengths are the same. What am I not understanding?

Comment: If they are all lists the same length then your penultimate line should do the trick. What's `key`? You check its length but then don't seem to use it. You could try `df <- cbind(filesystem_used_pct_value,system_core_user_pct_value,system_core_system_pct_value,system_memory_actual_used_pct_value,system_memory_swap_used_pct_value,system_cpu_total_pct_value,system_cpu_system_pct_value)`

Comment: Thank you Paul! cbind worked. Key was the datetime stamp of the metric bucket start